# Unable to get coroutine to start and stop when button is down

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I am working on the walking sounds for my game, I am wanting it to play a sound and then wait and play the next. As it is walking I only want it to do this when w is pressed. I have been trying to use an Enumerator to do so but I am having issues where it will not start the function.

```
  private IEnumerator audioPlayCoroutine;

public AudioSource[] steps;
public AudioSource[] cabinSteps;

private bool running;

void Start()
{
    running = false;

    audioPlayCoroutine = AudioPlay();
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    {
        if (running == false)
        {
            running = true;
        }
    }

    if (running == true)
    {
        StartCoroutine(audioPlayCoroutine);
    }

    else if (running == false)
    {
        StopCoroutine(audioPlayCoroutine);
    }

}
IEnumerator AudioPlay()
{
    int ran = Random.Range(0, 4);        

    steps[ran].Play();

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there are multiple reasons why it doesn't work:

For one `running` is never set to `false`. Once your player pressed `w` once, it will stay `true`.
Instead write

```
if (Input.GetKey("w"))
  running = true;
else
  running = false;
```

Additionally you start and stop your Coroutine multiple times.
Instead you should either check, whether the running status either changed or you should just check `running` in your coroutine.
It could then look like this:

```
void Start() {
  running = false;
  audioPlayCoroutine = AudioPlay();
  StartCoroutine(audioPlayCoroutine);
}

void Update() {
  if (Input.GetKey("w"))
    running = true;
  else
    running = false;
}

IEnumerator AudioPlay()
{
  while (true) {
    if(!running)
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);

    int ran = Random.Range(0, 4);  

    steps[ran].Play();

    // if you want it to play continuously, you can use the clip length for
    //   the sleep. This way it will start playing the next clip right after 
    //   this one is done. If you don't want that, go with your code
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(steps[ran].clip.length);
  }
}
```

If your clip is actually 2 seconds long, you might also want to interrupt it from playing once your user stops pressing the button.

Comment: You could gain some efficiency by leaving the coroutine itself unchanged and call StartCoroutine on GetKeyDown() and StopCoroutine on GetKeyUp()

Comment: @MarekLegris Maybe, but all you're doing is changing two boolean checks (`GetKey` and `!running`) for two others (KeyUp and KeyDown), so the performance would basically only be a method call vs. Starting and Stopping a Coroutine. So, while it might be faster, it might also not be (I'd need some benchmarks for that; Unless I'm really missing something) and I think the code is better readable like this, and I'd take that over a small performance boost.

Comment: Rating of Readability is personal preference and I respect that, just wanted to give my take on it.